# Colors of bars in MATLAB histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to color the bars in a MATLAB barplot as suggested below in the out-commented part of my code, however, when this part is included, it is throwing an error. How could I solve this?

```
x = [1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5];

b = bar(x)
% b.FaceColor = 'flat';
% b.CData(1,:).FaceColor = [0.4,0.6,0.8];        
% b.CData(2,:).FaceColor = [0.3,0.4,0.6];  


set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'\fontsize{16}Cond1', '\fontsize{16}Cond2', '\fontsize{16}Cond3'})

legend('\fontsize{16}Class1','\fontsize{16}Class2');
ylim([0 5.5])
ylabel('\fontsize{16}Intensities [V]')
title('\fontsize{16}Intensities for all conditions');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably try to use the new property `CData` of `bar` function, while you using a former version of matlab.
If you get the error that you wrote in the comments (why not in the question itself?), you should just omit the `CData`:

```
x = [1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5];
b = bar(x)
```

[image]

```
b(1).FaceColor = [0.4,0.6,0.8];
b(2).FaceColor = [0.3,0.4,0.6];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines don't look right:

```
b.CData(1,:).FaceColor = [0.4,0.6,0.8];
b.CData(2,:).FaceColor = [0.3,0.4,0.6];
```

You're looking for:

```
b.CData(1,:) = [0.4,0.6,0.8];
b.CData(2,:) = [0.3,0.4,0.6];
```

Comment: so, adding b.CData(1,:) = [0.4,0.6,0.8];
b.CData(2,:) = [0.3,0.4,0.6];  
is actually throwing me an error...

Comment: Have you tried replacing the commas with spaces (e.g. `[0.4 0.6 0.8]`)? I think that does the same thing however. Alternatively, what error message are you getting?

Comment: No appropriate method, property, or field 'CData' for class
'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.

Error in plotCorr (line 21)
b.CData(1,:) = [0.4,0.6,0.8];

Answer (score 1):

Please try that one:

```
x = [1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5;1.5,2.5];

b = bar(x);
b(1).FaceColor = [0.4,0.6,0.8];
b(2).FaceColor = [0.3,0.4,0.6];
```

I think it will do exactly what you want. Basically you need to index `b` object to get access to a different data set, and to change it's color you need to modify a `FaceColor` property.